# Layout bug in profile pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

A few days ago, I noticed a change to the layout of profile pages on the site:
[image: picture of a SFF.SE profile]

The blue box used to be higher up, with the elements up top further to the left.  Unless I'm missing something, the current profile page has a bug that has broken the familiar layout.

Chrome 19 shows this bug, along with Firefox 12 and 13.  Firefox 10 does not show the bug on this site, but does on some other SE sites.

Comment: Why was Tango's info blacked out? It's public info isn't it?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Real name and email address are not public information; location and age are.

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome 19. I see a similar layout bug on [security.se] and [bicycles.se], but not most other sites. In Firefox 10, [security.se] is also broken, but [bicycles.se] and [scifi.se] are fine.

Comment: The same bug is also appearing on [Physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1336/5878).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug affecting profile pages on a handful of sites. It should be fully fixed as of yesterday, but do let us know if you see issues again.